java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3": error=13, Permission denied
I have some problem, which occurs when executing PySpark on yarn.
The following error is reported when processing rdd: WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, node03, executor 3): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "-home-user-anaconda3-bin-python3": error=13, Permission denied
I have configured anaconda on all nodes and changed the anaconda directory to 777. I searched the entire web for solutions, but none of them worked.
This is my .bashrc file

    if [ -f "/home/user/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/user/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/user/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup

export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.2-1.cdh6.3.2.p0.1605554/lib/hadoop
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.2-1.cdh6.3.2.p0.1605554/lib/spark
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3

export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH

# JAVA
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

# added by Anaconda3 installer
export PATH="/home/zhenyu/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

#export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
#export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop

this is my warn:
enter image description here

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

After a day of trying, I have solved the problem, it was still a user permissions issue.
Check all permissions under this path and find that all users under -home have permissions of 700. You need to change them to 755 to solve the problem perfectly.
e.g. chmod 755 /home/user

Ideally, system wide anaconda installation is not installed under /home/user

Yes, in my system have many users, so, i just install anaconda under /home/user_name
